# B+tree with nodes not in leaf?

Tags: tree, b-tree

I have this [B+tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q2Rr.png). As far as I know, a B+tree has all of the nodes in the leaves, but in this B+tree some of the nodes are not in the leaf nodes (for instance 40 and 10). Why is that?

What would happen if I inserted an element that is already in the tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually, a B+Tree consists of two parts: the sequence set (all the leaves, containing keys and the actual data) and the index, which consists of all internal nodes and which contains only keys but no data. The only purpose of the index is to guide searches to the proper leaf page.

Keys in index nodes do not have to correspond to any keys actually stored in leaf nodes, since they only have to route searches to the right leaf. In other words, the index only needs separator keys, not record keys.

When a new key needs to be added to the index, an application might choose to modify it in some way so that it becomes more desirable in some fashion (e.g. shorter, in case of strings) while still retaining its ability to separate its left children from its right children. E.g. 'M' separates 'Lehmann' from 'Schulze' just as well as 'Müller' does. In the case of numeric keys, an application may chose the arithmetic mean between maximum left child and minimum right child, for example.

There is another reason why keys could occur in the index layer of a B+Tree without any corresponding 'record' keys in the leaves (sequence set), namely deletion. When a key is to be deleted from a B+Tree then it only gets removed from sequence set, which houses the actual data represented by the B+Tree. If there is a copy of the key in the index layer then that gets left alone, because it is still needed there for routing traffic.

If you insert a key that is already present in the sequence set then you violate a structural invariant of the B+Tree. The actual consequences of that corruption depend on the code that's using the B+Tree, but production-grade code will defend the invariants of its structures and most likely throw an exception in your face.